# How to add attribute default value to pre existing products?

Tags: magento, attributes, magento-1.7, product, listings

How to add attribute default value to pre existing products?

I created a Global Text area attribute and i added a default value into the text field. The problem that im running into is that the default value that i added is not showing up in the products that i created before i created this attribute.

The text field shows up in the previously created listings, but the default information is not showing up..

YES, this attribute has been added into a attribute set. 
I have cleared all the cache

Unique Value No

Values Required  yes

Input Validation for Store Owner  none

Apply To all products

Use in Quick Search  no

Use in Advanced Search  no

Comparable on Front-end no

Use In Layered Navigation  no

Use In Search Results Layered Navigation  no

Use for Promo Rule Conditions  no

Position  0

Enable WYSIWYG  yes

Visible on Product View Page on Front-end  yes

Used in Product Listing  no

Used for Sorting in Product Listing no

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Like i said at the beginning, i have already added the attribute set. Anyways, i found a solution to the problem..

Inside manage products, there is a action called “Update Attributes”. Select all the products that you want to update and then select Update Attributes and add all the new information in.

Comment: Thank you.  That also fixed it for me.  The default value wasn't being set for all the existing products until "Update Attributes" was used.